# How do I reverse the order of documents displayed on screen

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

The PDF documents are displayed on screen are in chronological order. They have been uploaded to the FILEMANAGER module in Wordpress. We need to reverse the order from 1 - 12 to 12 - 1. 12 being at the top of the list and 1 being at the bottom.

---

```
echo '<form name="myform" action="http://...." method="POST">';

$dirPath = dir('./wp-content/uploads/...');
$imgArray = array();
while (($file = $dirPath->read()) !== false)
{
  if ((substr($file, -3)=="pdf") || (substr($file, -3)=="xls") || (substr($file, -3)=="png"))
  {
     $imgArray[ ] = trim($file);
  }
}
$dirPath->close();
sort($imgArray);
$c = count($imgArray);
for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
{
    echo "<p class=\"downloads\">".ereg_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', getFilenameWithoutExt($imgArray[$i])) ." 
    <span class='complete'><a href=\"".get_home_url()."/wp-content/uploads/...".$imgArray[$i]."\" target=\"_blank\">
    [view]</a></span> <input name=\"group1[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"" . $imgArray[$i] . "\" /></p>";
}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="path" id="path" value="/wp-content/uploads/..." />
<input class="download" type="submit" value="  _ ">';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the image array by using `rsort`. You would results get in 12 to 1 order

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)`

To this:

`for($i=$c; $i>=0; $i--)`

That will reverse the output

Comment: that works but we now have an additional check box to the top document

Comment: And will the page reload when the check box is set? If so use @Sankalp's answer and check whether or not it's set the sort accordingly.